# Write global functions to use in all components in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, function, components

**Note : Its not for global variable but for a global common function to perform a functionality on all components**

I am working on an angular app where I have around 400 components in different modules, almost all components have one same kind of functionality as mentioned below

There is a sections on many pages which shows a "How to work section" which can be closed by users and will remain closed unless they open it again, I have done it with cookies which I set on click on close or open icon but this function is written in a component and this needs to be imported in other components

I want to create a functions somewhere which perform this functionality on click on icon and can be called without importing any component in others.

One way to do it ( as I thought ) could be create a JavaScript function in a file and load it in index file and then call this function on click on close and open icon

Not sure if this is the best way to do this. Hope someone will come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 21):

**1. create your global function service, i.e. 'funcs.services.ts' under 'services'** directory:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FuncsService {
  constructor() { }
  
  myGlobalAddFunction(a){
    return a++;
  }
  mySecondFunc(){
    // add more... and so on
  }
}
```

**2. Import the function in your component:**

```
// your path may different 
import { FuncsService } from './../services/funcs/funcs.service';
//...
constructor(
   private funcs: FuncsService
) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
   let x = 1;
   myResult = this.funcs.myGlobalAddFunction(x);
   // Then you are expecting 2 for return value
}
```

**3. Hope that works... :)**

Answer (score 14):

You can `export` a function that is a written in `.ts` file and then call it in all your components.

```
   export function myFunction(){
        // Do something
   }
```

And then import the function `myFunction()` in other components. That works fine for me and can be useful in certain cases

Comment: But this function is not available in component's markup...

Comment: Import the function into the component, then in the component's parameter declarations: `myFunction = myFunction` to make it available in the template.

Comment: I'm getting the issue: 'export' modifier cannot appear on class elements of this kind.ts(1031)

Answer (score 12):

This isn't the best solution (in my opinion). The best solution would be to either create a service, or an utils class.

But if you want to do this, I suggest you make a JS file, that you declare in your angular-cli.json file under the `scripts` property, containing your functions.

**EDIT** Now that you've came back to reason, here is a code sample to make utils classes.

```
export const IMG_UTILS = {
  convertPngToJpg = (picture: any) => {
    // Your logic here
  }
};

export const VIEW_MANAGER = {
  isAdblockActive = () => {
    // test if an ad-blocker is active
  }
};
```

You can make any utils class you want in a const, then put it into a file. Then, you can put this file in an utils folder, and request it with

```
import { VIEW_MANAGER } from 'src/app/utils/view-manager';
```

Otherwise, you can make a service, which is handled by Angular, with a console command such as

```
ng g s services/view-manager/view-manager
```

And it will behave the exact same way : you will import it in your components to use it.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yeah I thought of this but then it will be a javascript function, and I would require to use some variable's values from app

Comment: Oh no, not at all ! Just under your imports, you can just add `declare var myFunction: any;`, and now your function is available to you. That's actually how you use JS frameworks in typescript, such as jquery !

Comment: I have this condition on a template `*ngIf="!storeOptionVideoStatus"` how can I declare this in file included in cli file and how can it be used in template ?

Comment: In your file, you do `window['storeOptionVideoStatus'] = true;` (or false, or anything you want), and in your component, you create a getter like so `get storeOptionVideoStatus() { return window['storeOptionVideoStatus']; }`

Comment: Thanks , Solution is kind of executable but is there any article where I can read about this method and approach, as a newbie I am not if I can get it done properly .

Comment: Well both of the answers told you not to do that. But hey, I mean, it's our opinion, if it suits you better, then I will answer you in a way that you can use your solution. But again, if I was you, I would make either a service, or an utils class.

Comment: Ah , Now I get it . It was hard to decide because this was easy to implement and for obvious reason I will choose this. Now I will try will util class but your thought on it  will be great help for me ( may be on how I should do it )

Comment: may be you can modify your answer with code sample or explanation

Comment: Well, my thought is in my answer (: But anyways I edited it so that you have 2 examples on how to manage what you want with an utils file or a service.

Answer (score 6):

Just to chime in with possibly a duplicate answer albeit more fleshed out... I have a utilities class which I use.

For example:

```
export class Utilities {
    // Simple promise wrapper for setTimeout. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api
    public static Wait = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

The class is referenced in a component via the `import` statement:

```
import { Utilities } from 'path/to/Utilities';
```

And then you can call your static methods thus:

```
Utilities.Wait(30000)
    .then(() => DoStuff())
    .catch(() => console.log('Darn!'));
```

I would tend to use RxJs but I've written it this way to keep things a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The most recommended way is to use a service and inject it whenever needed, but there is a way to have a function available **globally**.

Although I don't think it's a really good idea, you can add the function in the index.html file, then whenever you want to use it, you have to use `@ts-ignore` to avoid an error from being thrown.
e.g

index.html

```
<script>
  function globalFunc(){
    alert(2)
  }
</script>
```

anywhere else on the app

```
// @ts-ignore
globalFunc();
```

1. List item

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use it without inject in constructor and import in each time, just set all global functions as static

```
 static sortById(data : any[]):any[] {
    return data.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id))
}
```

then use it anywhere in your project

```
GlobalHelper.sortById(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution for calling the google analytics gtag function (which is a global function on the Window object) in my services:

I add this to my AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent {
  ... component stuff
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    gtag(arg0: string, arg1: string): void;
  }
}
```

Then in all areas where you need to call that function, add the reference to window:

```
export class MyService {

  myMethod(): void {
    // do stuff...

    // then send event 
    window.gtag('event', 'details');
  }
}
```